# Very Simple <a href> link isn't working (works when right clicked)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I am having trouble with my Store < a href> I want it to redirect to the store page which is on a different site. it works when you right click it and select "Open Tab" or "Open new tab", but not when you regularly click it. I've tried moving around different things and checking to see if everything's right.

Thanks.

```
<!-- Navigation panel ================================================== -->
<nav class="main-nav dark transparent menu fixed">
  <div class="transparent wrapper relative clearfix">
    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <div class="nav-wrapper large-nav float-left">
      <ul class="clearlist">        
        <!-- Item With Sub -->
        <li>
          <a href="http://mylink.abc"class="active">Store</a> 
        </li>
        <!-- End Item With Sub -->
      </ul>
    </div>  
    <!-- End Main Menu -->  
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- End Navigation panel -->
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, try to see if our mouse buttons are different

Comment: My mouse bottoms are fine, tried on both my PC and Mac.

Comment: Maybe the space between `"` and `class`?

Comment: @ChrisHappy Space doesnt matter, try reproducing it without space or with space... it works

Comment: You tried clicking it more than once ?

Comment: @Jones Vinoth Joseph Yes

Comment: I think it is a css overlap, please post css code.

Comment: The website is : http://godswillnyc.com/

Comment: <!-- CSS -->
 
 <!--A dead simple, responsive boilerplate-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css"/> 
 
 <!--Preloader-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialPreloader.css">
 
 <!--Icon font-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/Icon-font-7/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/etlinefont/etlinefont.css" />

Comment: Thank you very much @Avistein, but the site is godswillnyc.com and it doesn't work. I tried that, but there are other things in the code that I think is blocking the buttons from working.

Comment: Is everyone supposed to guess at what these "other things" are? Please create a [minimal, reproducible, example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: check your `script.js:menuSub.on('click')`, and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See your `script.js` file on line number `643` and `646` there is a `return false` statement.

Remove that statement.

Because it is triggered by clicking on the link and it returns false. Links which have a `return false` in their `onClick` event wont take you to the corresponding `href`

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the "http" and it works! Also with "https" it works. Weird though!

```html
 <!-- Navigation panel
    ================================================== -->      
    <nav class="main-nav dark transparent menu fixed">
        <div class="transparent wrapper relative clearfix">
            <!-- Main Menu -->
            <div class="nav-wrapper large-nav float-left">
                    <ul class="clearlist">              
                        <!-- Item With Sub -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="godswillnyc.com" class="active">Store</a>    
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item With Sub -->
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Main Menu -->  
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation panel -->
```

Comment: Did it not work for you if you included `http` or `https` ?

Comment: It works with https or without including either protocol.But surprisingly not working when you add http .Tried with my own website ,and the result is same !

Comment: @Avistein Thank you very much but it still does not work, I got rid of the http, It may be something in my CSS.

Comment: Try adding `target="_blank"` in the a tag

Answer (score 0):

It works in my PC.

Can it show an address when your mouse enter the a tag like this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI5aW.png)

May the other TAGs display above it if it cant show hover style.

Answer (score 0):

- First: it works on my PC.
- Second: You should take a look at browser console. Maybe it will get this error:

  Refused to display 'https://www.google.com.vn/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=5w1mWMz2LZHD8AfEkbWABQ&gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Your target link disallow loading from outside of their domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your `script.js` discard default behavior by returning `false` on `click` event:

```
menuSub.on("click",function(){
 // ...
 return false; // <-- here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

href="http://mylink.abc"class="active"

Umm, there should be a space between href and class or maybe it's my browser's issue loading this comment.